How to resolve Mono class libraries being out of sync with mono runtime
I am creating a mod using MelonLoader v0.6.6.  I'm modding a unity game made with version Unity 2021.3.16f1.  Most functionality works, however, some function calls fail and I get the following error:

cant resolve internal call to "UnityEngine.JsonUtility::FromJsonInternal" (tested without signature also)


Your mono runtime and class libraries are out of sync.
The out of sync library is: E:\Steam Games\steamapps\common\ATLYSS\ATLYSS_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.JSONSerializeModule.dll


When you update one from git you need to update, compile and install
the other too.
Do not report this as a bug unless you're sure you have updated correctly:
you probably have a broken mono install.
If you see other errors or faults after this message they are probably related
and you need to fix your mono install first.
cant resolve internal call to "UnityEngine.JsonUtility::FromJsonInternal" (tested without signature also)

This causes the function call to fail and typically the mod crashes afterward.  The issue is hindering my ability to do what I am trying to do.  This is just one function that causes the problem.  The other functions give the same error.
I have tried building the app using a multitude of .NET versions, including .NET Standard 2.1 (the recommended for that Unity version), Framework 4.6.2, 4.7.2, 4.8, 4.5.2, 4.0, 3.5 (incompatible), some others.  I have used the MelonLoader template generator and selected the game I'm modding, and it inputs all assembly references required and builds the starting point project, and the bug still occurs.  I have made a blank slate application and manually selected each and every assembly reference manually and have the same problem.  I have installed multiple versions of mono and they all cause the same problem (I'm not even certain any of the installations made any difference to what was used to build the mod in Visual Studio).  I have been at it for a while and need advice.  I've read countless posts that don't shed any light on the issue.  Any help is appreciated.
Below is a minimal example that causes the error:
using MelonLoader;
using HarmonyLib;
using UnityEngine;

[assembly: MelonInfo(typeof(ServerCapModifier.Core), "ServerCapModifier", "1.5.0", "Stunted Raccoon", null)]
[assembly: MelonGame("KisSoft", "ATLYSS")]

namespace ServerCapModifier {
    public class Core : MelonPlugin {
        [HarmonyPatch(typeof(AtlyssNetworkManager), nameof(AtlyssNetworkManager.OnStartServer))]
        public static class AtlyssNetworkManager_OnStartServer {
            public static void Prefix(ref AtlyssNetworkManager __instance) {
                Melon<Core>.Logger.Msg("Called OnStartServer prefix");
            }
        }
    }
}

NOTE: I believe it may be some kind of timing issue.  I had this error when trying to use the UnityEngine JSON module to parse some JSON , but relocating the JSON parsing from OnPreInitialization() to OnInitializeMelon() fixed that specific issue.  However, simply making a prefix patch to some functions like shown above still causes the issue.  So the issue persists there.
